# WebStorm: show unused AngularJS dependencies

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

Let's say I have the following AngularJS controller:

```
function MyController($scope, unusedService, myService) {
    $scope.something = function() {};
    myService.doSomething();
}
```

How can I make WebStorm show the `unusedService` as an unused parameter, because it currently doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In **Settings | Editor | Inspections | JavaScript | General | Unused local symbol** inspection settings, set **Ignore unused parameters:** to **None**

[image]